Unable to run LocalStack as a part of integration test
I'm trying to set up LocalStack to be a part of my tests and I'm getting following error:
❌ Deployment failed: Error: FirestoreListener: SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version not found. Has the environment been bootstrapped? Please run 'cdk bootstrap' (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html)
I'm trying to follow hello-world example from LocalStack documentation and this is my code
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { TestStack} from './testStack';

const app = new cdk.App();
let stack = new TestStack(app, 'FirestoreListenerStack', {
    stackName: 'FirestoreListener',
    env: {
        account: process.env.ACCOUNT_ID == null ? '000000000000' : process.env.ACCOUNT_ID,
        region: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION == null ? 'eu-west-1' : process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
    }
});

import {Duration, Stack, StackProps} from "aws-cdk-lib";
import {Topic} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-sns";
import {SqsSubscription} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-sns-subscriptions";
import {Construct} from "constructs";
import {Queue} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs";

export class TestStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const queue = new Queue(this, 'TestAppQueue', {
      visibilityTimeout: Duration.seconds(300)
    });

    const topic = new Topic(this, 'TestAppTopic');

    topic.addSubscription(new SqsSubscription(queue));
  }}


and that a test I'm trying to use:
import {LocalstackContainer} from "@testcontainers/localstack";
import {execSync} from 'child_process';

const region: string = 'eu-west-2'
const account: string = '000000000000'

describe('lambdaHandler', () => {
    let container: any;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        container = await new LocalstackContainer().start();

        const endpoint = `http://${container.getHost()}:${container.getMappedPort(4566)}`;
        process.env.ACCOUNT_ID = account
        execSync('echo Hello World!', { encoding: 'utf-8' , stdio: 'inherit'});
        execSync(`cd ./infrastructure && cdklocal bootstrap aws://${account}/${region}`, {
            env: {
                ...process.env,
                ACCOUNT_ID: account,
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'test',
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'test',
                AWS_REGION: region,
                AWS_ENDPOINT_URL: endpoint,
            },
            stdio: 'inherit'
        });
        execSync(`cd ./infrastructure && cdklocal deploy --require-approval never`, {
            env: {
                ...process.env,
                ACCOUNT_ID: account,
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'test',
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'test',
                AWS_REGION: region,
                AWS_ENDPOINT_URL: endpoint,
            },
            stdio: 'inherit'
        });
    })

    afterAll(async () => {
        await container.stop();
    })

    it("sample test", async () => {

    });
});

I see that env seems to be bootstrapped:
⏳  Bootstrapping environment aws://000000000000/eu-west-2...
Trusted accounts for deployment: (none)
Using default execution policy of 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess'. Pass '--cloudformation-execution-policies' to customize.
Trusted accounts for lookup: (none)
CDKToolkit: creating CloudFormation changeset...
CDKToolkit |  0/15 | 12:56:08 PM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | CDKToolkit 
CDKToolkit |  1/15 | 12:56:08 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::KMS::Key           | FileAssetsBucketEncryptionKey 
CDKToolkit |  2/15 | 12:56:08 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::KMS::Alias         | FileAssetsBucketEncryptionKeyAlias 
CDKToolkit |  3/15 | 12:56:09 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::S3::Bucket         | StagingBucket 
CDKToolkit |  4/15 | 12:56:09 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::S3::BucketPolicy   | StagingBucketPolicy 
CDKToolkit |  5/15 | 12:56:09 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::ECR::Repository    | ContainerAssetsRepository 
CDKToolkit |  6/15 | 12:56:09 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::Role          | FilePublishingRole 
CDKToolkit |  7/15 | 12:56:09 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::Role          | ImagePublishingRole 
CDKToolkit |  8/15 | 12:56:09 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::Role          | LookupRole 
CDKToolkit |  9/15 | 12:56:09 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::Policy        | FilePublishingRoleDefaultPolicy 
CDKToolkit | 10/15 | 12:56:09 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::Policy        | ImagePublishingRoleDefaultPolicy 
CDKToolkit | 11/15 | 12:56:09 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::Role          | CloudFormationExecutionRole 
CDKToolkit | 12/15 | 12:56:09 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy | CdkBoostrapPermissionsBoundaryPolicy 
CDKToolkit | 13/15 | 12:56:09 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::SSM::Parameter     | CdkBootstrapVersion 
CDKToolkit | 14/15 | 12:56:10 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::Role          | DeploymentActionRole 
CDKToolkit | 15/15 | 12:56:10 PM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | CDKToolkit 
 ✅  Environment aws://000000000000/eu-west-2 bootstrapped.

My main goal is to use my existing stack and deploy it on localstack using test containers which would allow me to write better tests, however there might be a better way to achieve the same?
I manually run LocalStack using localstack start -d and then commands like cdk bootstrap and cdk deploy works smooth. JS/TS is not my first language of choice so perhaps there is something obvious in my approach that doesn't allow me to follow the same approach inside a test.

I've managed to fix it by removing aws://${account}/${region} from cdk bootstrap command

We also offer CDK-local package that can make the initial setup a bit easier, it can save you some setup time (if you can use it in your CI)
https://github.com/localstack/aws-cdk-local
You can find some additional information on using CDK here

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
